# jQuery slideToggle dynamically adjust location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jQuery and I'm not sure how to solve this problem. My issue is hard to explain, but basically I have button boxes with `display: inline-block;`. When I click on a button, a menu `slideToggle`'s down below. Depending on the page size, there are 2-8ish buttons that can be on one line. In the html, the slide out menu comes right after its respective button, and before the next one. This obviously makes any button that comes after the slide out list drop down below the list.

Here's my basic setup: https://jsfiddle.net/cr1fev67/

Not sure how to fix this...some kind of simple structural changes or jQuery magic to check the browser window size and insert the list after the last button element of the respective line??

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe position absolute? https://jsfiddle.net/cr1fev67/1/

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/cr1fev67/2/ if this is what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Would ideally like to still be able to see the blocks under but this isn't a bad solution, thanks. Also would like if, for example, the far right button would cause the list to open maxed out to the right, but I can probably mess with that and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can just change the CSS of list to absolute to achieve what you want.

But if you want to still see the buttons beneath the list, then you're probably going to have to re-arrange your HTML.

Some pseudo-code:

```
<div>Button1</div>
<div>Button2</div>
<div>Button3</div>

<div>List1</div>
<div>List2</div>
<div>List3</div>
```

If each of the lists have a variable amount of options within it, I'd suggest using JavaScript on document.ready to change the amount.

Comment: I have two issues with this approach. 1 - How to "link" button with list in jQuery. Right now the way I do this is with this, parent & next/prev. My jQuery would have to recognize whichever button was being pressed and open the corresponding list. Like I said, I'm an extreme newbie. 2 - I forgot what my second issue was after typing the first one.